# How to get value of Model when iterating over collection in Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I have a collection of Items in a ViewModel that I am iterating over like below using Knockout.js.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Items">
      <div>
          My HTML to modify as needed
      </div>
 </div>
```

Each item of the list has an `int` field `myInt` inside of it that I want to set as the unique id + some string, so that the HTML element id is like `id=myItem1234`

How do I do this with a data-bind via Knockout.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some work, I was able to get this using the following data-bind:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Items">
    <div data-bind="attr: {'id': 'myItem' + $data.myInt()}">
         My HTML to modify as needed
    </div>
 </div>
```

This created a unique html element like `myItem1234` when the page rendered. It was the `$data` that allowed me to get to the specific element I was iterating over and then `myInt()` allowed me to access the value of my specific field. This will come in handy beyond just my specific case above.